# OpenVINO cannot convert MLP Mixer TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, openvino, mlp

I use this [GitHub](https://github.com/bangoc123/mlp-mixer) repository to train MLP Mixer TensorFlow 2.5.0 model.

[image]

And I try to generate .bin and .xml files with the command

```
mo --data_type FP16 --saved_model_dir C:\Users\john0\Desktop\mlp --input_shape (1,150,150,3)
```

The following is the error I faced.

```
[ WARNING ]  Failed to parse a tensor with Unicode characters. Note that Inference Engine does not support string literals, so the string constant should be eliminated from the graph.
[ WARNING ]  Failed to parse a tensor with Unicode characters. Note that Inference Engine does not support string literals, so the string constant should be eliminated from the graph.
[ ERROR ]  Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID" (<class 'openvino.tools.mo.front.user_data_repack.UserDataRepack'>): Original placeholders: 'serving_default_input_1, saver_filename'. Freezing was requested for ''. --input_shape was provided without --input. Can not deduce which node shape to override
```

I use openvino_2022.1.0.643 version.

And you can download my model [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Km2B3JVc7a2ur3dknnZmszyEq7wf0cQD/view?usp=share_link).

Comment: Which TensorFlow version did you use?

Comment: TensorFlow 2.5.0

Comment: Do you have the Keras (.h5) model? If yes, please share it. And which script did you use to convert the model to saved_model format?

Comment: Hi Zul, I just save my model to saved_model format directly without saving .h5 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the model having multiple inputs, and can be resolved using this MO command `mo --data_type FP16 --saved_model_dir model\directory\mlp\ --input_shape (1..,150,150,3)`. However, I'm getting  different errors now:

```
[ ERROR ]  List of operations that cannot be converted to Inference Engine IR:
[ ERROR ]      FusedBatchNormV3 (16)
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block/layer_normalization/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block/layer_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_1/layer_normalization_2/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_1/layer_normalization_3/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_2/layer_normalization_4/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_2/layer_normalization_5/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_3/layer_normalization_6/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_3/layer_normalization_7/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_4/layer_normalization_8/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_4/layer_normalization_9/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_5/layer_normalization_10/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_5/layer_normalization_11/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_6/layer_normalization_12/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_6/layer_normalization_13/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_7/layer_normalization_14/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]          StatefulPartitionedCall/mlp_mixer/mlp_block_7/layer_normalization_15/FusedBatchNormV3
[ ERROR ]  Part of the nodes was not converted to IR. Stopped.
```

As you can see, the FusedBatchNormV3 layer in your model is not supported in TensorFlow 2, you can refer to [Supported Framework Layers](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html) for a list of supported operations for TensorFlow 2.